# Replace values that are not INT with 0 in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a `pandas DataFrame` which looks like this.

```
 ----------
|audi_id   |
 ----------
|     1    |
|     2    |
|     3    |
|     4    |
|    abc   |
-----------
```

I need to replace any value that contains a string value, with a 0.

I currently have this code here to replace all non `int` values to `str` but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone please help?

```
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

-

```
df['test'] = pd.to_numeric(df.audit_id[:, 0], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Output I expect is:

```
 ----------
|audi_id   |
 ----------
|     1    |
|     2    |
|     3    |
|     4    |
|     0    |
-----------
```

Comment: check this: [pandas replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df.audit_id[:, 0]` is not ok.  You need to do either `df.loc[:, 'audit_id']` or `df.audit_id`

```
df['test'] = pd.to_numeric(df.audit_id, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

That said, you might want integers instead of float

```
df['test'] = pd.to_numeric(df.audit_id, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a dataframe like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id_a':['a','b','c','d','e'],'sudi_id':[1,2,'abc',4,'efg']})
```

output:

```
    id_a    sudi_id
0   123     1
1   234     2
2   345     abc
3   567     4
4   789     efg
```

Run:

```
df['sudi_id']=df['sudi_id'].apply(lambda x: x if np.isreal(x) else 0)
```

Output:

```
    id_a    sudi_id
0   123     1
1   234     2
2   345     0
3   567     4
4   789     0
```

if this works for you, please vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to match any row with upper or lower case letters and set their value = 0

```
df['audi_id'] = df['audi_id'].replace(regex='([a-zA-Z])', value=0)
```